# Evaluate Density of transformed Normal

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose $v\sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$ and I obtain $w = Av \sim \mathcal{N}(0, AA^\top)$ for some matrix $A$. My intuition tells me that the density of these two points under the respective distributions should be the same. Is it true?

I'll work with the log density as it's easier. For the first one we have
$$
-\frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi) - \frac{1}{2}v^\top v
$$
For the second one we have
$$
-\frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi) -\frac{1}{2}\log\det(AA^\top) -\frac{1}{2}w^\top(AA^\top)^{-1}w = -\frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi) - \log\det(A)-\frac{1}{2}v^\top v
$$
So it seems that the density differs by a factor depending on the determinant
$$
\mathcal{N}(v\mid 0, I) = \frac{1}{\det(A)} \mathcal{N}(w\mid 0, AA^\top)
$$
Is this correct? And what's the intuition behind this?

Answer (score 0):

The densities are not scalar multiples of each other. Notice that that would imply that the integral of at least one of them is something other than $1.$

Notice also that one of them has $\frac 1 2 w^\top(AA^\top)^{-1} w$ where the other has $\frac 1 2 w^\top w.$

Comment: Doesn't that cancel out though? 
$$
w^\top (AA^\top)^{-1} w = (Av)^\top (AA^\top)^{-1}  (Av) = v^\top A^\top A^{-\top} A^{-1} A v = v^\top v
$$

Comment: And I have used the fact that $-\frac{1}{2}\log\det(AA^\top) = -\frac{1}{2}\log(\det(A) \det(A^\top)) = -\frac{1}{2}\log(\det(A)^2) = -\log\det(A)$

Comment: @Physics_Student : But what is the relationship between $dw$ and $dv\text{?} \qquad$

Comment: @Physics_Student : Consider, for example, the case where $A$ is $10$ times the identity matrix.

Comment: I am so confused not gonna lie..